exist any way to get a simple global config for ansiColor var for outputs/steps build jop pipeline results?
exist any way to get a global ansiColor var for outputs/steps build jop results?
I showed results all text in black color.
Objetive: Show diferents blocks results in a diferents colors
Thanks in advance
Regards,
Edu < allways learning

Two step process:

Install ansicolor plugin and enable it globally
Add ANSI escape codes to your echo statements

In the most basic way it would be like this:
echo 'Some \033[1m bold \033[0m text'

obviously you can create constants for different codes, define wrapper methods - the sky is the limit.

By wrapper methods I mean something like echoInRed() that prints text in red. What makes you think it was me who downvoted your question?
